# How to display images from web in gallery view in android

Tags: android, galleryview

I displayed images to the gallery view with images in drawable folder.
MyCode

```
public class GalleryView extends Activity {
Integer[] pics = {
  R.drawable.antartica1,
  R.drawable.antartica2,
  R.drawable.antartica3,
  R.drawable.antartica4,
  R.drawable.antartica5,
  R.drawable.antartica6,
  R.drawable.antartica7,
  R.drawable.antartica8,
  R.drawable.antartica9,
  R.drawable.antartica10
};
ImageView imageView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
    ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
 long arg3) {
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
  "You have selected picture " + (arg2+1) + " of Antartica", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);

}

    });

}



}
```

But I have images in an arraylist like this

```
[http://sport24x7.com/nightclub/photos/ 9955917512-Gym-ChestWorkout_xxlarge.jpg, http://sport24x7.com/nightclub/photos/ 64557264beginner_gym_workout_legs_large.jpg, http://sport24x7.com/nightclub/photos/ 54809160intro-ez-bar.jpg]
```

How to show these images in gallery view. Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: You should picasso library:
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);

Comment: Picasso web site: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: you should follow the lazy loading concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should download images and then display them with Gallery.
i recommend you to use [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: this answer should be in comment

Comment: But I need to display the images in gallery view of xml not grid view

Answer (score 0):

Note that [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) view is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

[Here](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) is a simple tutorial on how to use GridView to display images.

The key concept is to override `getView` and load your images into the `ImageView`. You can easily load the images given the URL using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

For example in your Adapter's `getView`:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the image from the web and convert the stream to `Bitmap`

Try the below code.

```
URL imageUrl = new URL(item);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

I would suggest lazy loading. Try [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)